# Single function that iterates over a list and does two actions, or two functions that each do their own action and iterate over the list separately?

Tags: language-agnostic, refactoring

As the title says, which of the two is the better option?

1) A single function that iterates over a list and does action A and B.

2) Two separate functions that each do their own action and iterate over the list separately.

For a very simple example, suppose in a list of integers you wanted to multiply each integer by 3, but you also wanted to count the number of integers that were odd, after this multiplying by 3. Would it be better to do this in one function? Or better to multiply by 3 and count the odd integers in separate functions?

The first option would be faster since you only need to iterate over the list once. However, it would also violate the rule of each function doing only one action. Likewise, the second option would run slower, but would be more easily readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are talking about quality of code, don't give much importance to performance as there is no way to be sure until you actually perform rigorous profiling on your code.

And splitting a loop usually will not have a big performance hit unless you are dealing with billions of records. Most modern compiler are very efficient in optimizing so your assumptions might just turn out to be wrong.

Now lets look at some of the benefits of splitting the loops

### More readability

One of the drawbacks of procedural code is that it is difficult to know which parts of the code are related until you read all the code. So if there are two actions in the same loop I don't know if they are related or not until I read the entire loop. This can make it very difficult to make changes.

With the loops split and preferably in different functions I am sure that the 2 actions are not related so I can freely refactor one without affecting the other.

### Less local variables

Loops which perform a single action and calculates a single value can just return that value. This means that you don't need to accumulate values in multiple local variables in your code, which makes it easy to refactor your code.

Split loops usually creates opportunity for more refactoring as now you have a better understanding of your code, and it is easier to modify.

At the end if you do get a hit in performance, you can always combine the loops again.